# Is there a way to select table object that is just pasted into a word document using vsto c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, vsto

I'm trying to copy a table from an Excel book and paste it into a word document.
Currently it works fine with "range.Paste()", but I need to select the table in the word document I just pasted and do some formatting.
Is there a way to specify (select) a table that is just active, or just pasted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. Maybe it can help others that face the same issue.
After pasting, you can retrieve the first table in the range and it will be the table you just pasted ;

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table ret2 = range.Tables[1];
```